# Git commands open a line to type text instead of being executed

Tags: linux, gitlab

I've cloned a repository from gitlab.com.
But when I go inside the directory, commands just open a new line to enter text instead of being executed.

[image: GIT error]

EDIT:
I've cloned another repository from gitlab.com in another directory, and it's working as intended, when I enter there and go for example for a `git status` I get:

```
# On branch dev
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Went back to the repository I'm having troubles with. Removed it with `git remote rm origin` (Didn't have troubles running that command). Deleted the directory, cloned it again, but the same continues to happen.
I guess something must be wrong with that repository, but what?

NOTES: 
1. It's running on AWS, I'm just using Putty console.
2. Changed to root just in case privileges were causing the strange behavior. With my user didn't work either.

Comment: Running as `root` probably isn't good, but I don't know if `git` balks at that or not.

Comment: it looks like git command is hanging.  try running `GIT_TRACE=1 git status` and see if that shows anything?

Comment: Changed to root just in case privileges were causing the strange behavior. With my user didn't work either.

Comment: After running "GIT_TRACE=1 git status" . It shows: "trace: built-in: git 'status'" and another new line to continue entering text. Have to go for another CTRL-C to go back to the prompt line.

Comment: Maybe it's just slow. Git on Windows with large repositories can take a while. How long have you waited for `git status` to display something? Open the Windows Task Manager and see if there's CPU and/or disk activity.

Comment: It's running on AWS, I'm just using Putty console.The response time showing the next empty line is zero.

Comment: Rebase your MSYS or Cygwin programs and libraries. Check their FAQ...

Comment: I don't have troubles with other repositories. Only with that one in particular. Just edited the question.

Comment: Then I guess git can't connect and the network timeout is too large. I remember this happening for me in the past. It took like 3 minutes for git to finally print an error message.

Comment: It's just slow, let it execute for a while.

Comment: Thanks Nikos and Kamil, that was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As [Nikos C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/856199/nikos-c) and [Kamil Cuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9072753/kamil-cuk) commented, it was just taking time to retrieve the result (Over 2 minutes).

It was just slow, I did let it execute for a couple of minutes.